# How can I compare two multidimensional arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm trying to compare two multidimensional arrays that contain an ID and a timestamp. I want to filter them depending on 1. **id and timestamp are identical**, 2. **id is identical but not timestam**p, and 3. **id is different**.
The array "queryData" has 5000 entries aprox while "news" has 30.
Examples of both arrays:

```
queryData = [["#12345", 2020-03-23T22:00:00], ["#45678", 2020-03-30T22:00:00], ...] // + 4000 more arrays
news = [[
  '#40723443',
  'NISSAN LEAF 40kWh Acenta 5p.',
  'juke',
  'nissan',
  'Eléctrico',
  '2018',
  'N/D km',
  27500,
  25750,
  true,
  'valencia',
  2020-05-02T22:00:00.000Z
],
[
  '#45236145',
  'FORD Tourneo Custom 2.0 Ecoblue 96kW 130CV Hybrid L1 Trend 5p.',
  'tourneo_custom',
  'ford',
  'Híbrido',
  '2020',
  'N/D km',
  32800,
  30990,
  true,
  'avila',
  2020-04-30T22:00:00.000Z
],
[
  '#42489509',
  'HYUNDAI i20 1.2 MPI Essence LE 5p.',
  'i20',
  'hyundai',
  'Gasolina',
  '2019',
  'N/D km',
  13600,
  11850,
  true,
  'barcelona',
  2020-04-30T22:00:00.000Z
], [
  '#45225249',
  'MERCEDES-BENZ Clase B B 200 d 5p.',
  'clase_b',
  'mercedes-benz',
  'Diésel',
  '2020',
  'N/D km',
  38500,
  36500,
  true,
  'barcelona',
  2020-04-28T22:00:00.000Z
],
[
  '#45297851',
  'OPEL Corsa 1.2T XHL 74kW 100CV GSLine 5p.',
  'corsa',
  'opel',
  'Gasolina',
  '2020',
  'N/D km',
  16700,
  14400,
  true,
  'vizcaya',
  2020-04-24T22:00:00.000Z
], ...] // + 28 more arrays
```

This is the code:

```
for (let y = 0; y < queryData.length; y++){
                for (let i = 0; i < news.length; i++) {
                    if (news[i][11] > queryData[y][1] && queryData[y][0] === news[i][0]) { // older date and same id
                        nothing[i] = news[i];

                    } else if (news[i][11] < queryData[y][1] && queryData[y][0] === news[i][0]) { // newer date and same id 
                        existentID[i] = news[i];

                    } else { // different id
                        newCar[i] = news[i];

                    }
                }

            }
```

However, in the console log appears that the **arrays filter all of them in the first condition and the last.** For example, if all the arrays inside "news" are new, like in this case, they appear in the variables nothing and newCar, when they should be just inside newCar.

Result with console.logs:

```
newCar 30
existentID 0
nothing 30
```

Can it be due to the loop? I don't understand why the elements appear double in these two conditions.
Thank you!!

Comment: are you sure about `news[i][11]`? is the larger array sorted? can you have more than one item with the same date? can you add a bigger data set for testing?

Comment: yes! sorry about that! I've already changed to make it more understandable. It is sorted by the timestamp and yes, most of the 30 items will have the same date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could collect all `id` with their timestamps (if more than one) and iterate the new data set and assign to appropriate array.

This approach uses only two loops.

```js
var queryData = [["#12345", "2020-03-23T22:00:00"], ["#45678", "2020-03-30T22:00:00"]], 
    news = [["#12345", "2020-05-02T22:00:00"], ["#31586", "2020-01-05T22:00:00"]],
    query = queryData.reduce((r, [id, date]) => {
        if (!r[id]) r[id] = {};
        r[id][date] = true;
        return r;
    }, {}),
    result = news.reduce((r, a) => {
        if (!query[a[0]]) r.newCar.push(a);
        else if (query[a[0]][a[1]]) r.existentID.push(a);
        else  r.nothing.push(a);
        return r;
    }, { nothing: [], existentID: [], newCar: [] });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try instead of assigning on id/index. Push in the array..

`nothing[i] = news[i];`

**should be**

`nothing.push(news[i])`

When you assign directly on array, since javascript array is dynamic in nature it create that many element in array.

**Sample:**

```
let x  = []
x[10] = 10
console.log(x.length) // 11

let y  = []
y.push(10)
console.log(y.length) // 1
```

**Updated Solution:**

```
queryData = [
  ["#12345", "2020-03-23T22:00:00"],
  ["#45678", "2020-03-30T22:00:00"],
]; // + 4000 more arrays
news = [
  ["#12345", "2020-05-02T22:00:00"],
  ["#31586", "2020-01-05T22:00:00"],
]; // + 28 more arrays
newCar = [];
nothing = [];
existentID = [];
for (let y = 0; y < queryData.length; y++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < news.length; i++) {
    if (news[i][11] > queryData[y][1] && queryData[y][0] === news[i][0]) {
      nothing.push(news[i])
    } else if (
      news[i][11] < queryData[y][1] &&
      queryData[y][0] === news[i][0]
    ) {
      // newer date and same id
      existentID.push(news[i])
    } else {
      // different id
      newCar.push(news[i])
    }
  }
}
console.log(newCar, nothing, existentID)
console.log(newCar.length, nothing.length, existentID.length)
```